# Usar the_title() o get_the_title() en un plugin (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-api

Me complace saludarlos.

Estoy trabajando con una API y tratando de crear un plugin personalizado.
Lo que intento es crear un plugin `que me permita obtener el titulo de la publicacion actual`, con el fin de concatenarlo al final del enlace de la API y poder obtener la informacion que necesito del registro exacto, es decir, del registro con el nombre de la pagina.

La API la he creado yo y funciona correctamente, la he puesto a prueba muchas situaciones y por ahi no hay ningun problema. Con solo buscar a traves del `/mi_api.php?name=Algun Elemento` es suficiente para mostrar un registro, pero mi idea es hacerlo dinamico, y para ello requiero poder usar el `get_the_name` o `the_title` para dicho fin.

He probado en mi `archivo de plugin`:

```
$url = "https://.../.../mi_api.php?name=Mandarinas Chinas";
$url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $url);
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

Y funciona correctamente, ya que `echo $data['name'];` `en la plantilla` muestra el nombre del registro.

Pero al hacerlo dinamico a traves de concatenar `get_the_title()` con la `url`:

```
$titulo = get_the_title();

$url = "https://.../.../mi_api.php?name=" . $titulo;
$url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $url);
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

No hace nada, solo imprime `"https://.../.../mi_api.php?name="` fuera de sitio.

Luego al hacer exactamnete lo mismo pero con `the_title()` :

```
$titulo = the_title();

$url = "https://.../.../mi_api.php?name=" . $titulo;
$url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $url);
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

Simplemente no hace nada.

En este punto creeo que `get_the_title()` y `the_title()` no funcionan en el contexto del plugin.

Alguna idea? Muchas gracias!

---

### Postdata:

Con que pueda ejecutar exactamente esto dentro del plugin estaria super complacido y mi duda resuelta totalmente:

```
$titulo = the_title();
$url = "https://.../.../mi_api.php?name=" . $titulo;
$url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $url);
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

¿Còmo obtener / llamar / capturar el `title` de la pagina actual? Con el titulo concatenado a la url podria iterar dentro de los elementos de la API segun el nombre de la pagina. La API fue creada convenientemente para coincidir los nombres de cada serie de registros con el nombre de las paginas.

Una vez pueda acceder a la pagina actual, los registros seran mostrados de la siguiente manera en la plantilla:

```
echo $data['name'];
...
echo $data['spoiler'];
```

Y eso seria para mi mas que suficiente en cuanto a funcionalidad, ya que la API la necesito para cargar algunos datos (4300 registros con 47 variables cada uno) e inemdiatamente sera desconectada.

He logrado hacer exactamente la funcionalidad que quiero directamente en el archivo de plantilla de Wordpress, funciona correctamente, obtengo todos los valores, puedo procesarlos y todo funciona de maravillas, pero mi idea de hacerlo en un plugin es para no mezclar codigo, en especial porque debo tratar algunos datos de la API antes de usarlos en dicha plantilla, entonces es de esperarse un poco de codigo espageti que quiero evitar, por ello busco trabajar la API y el procesamiento de algunos datos en un archivo independiente del archivo de la plantilla, para mantener el orden y poder desactivar la API simplemenete desde la ventana de Plugins de wordpress.

E idealmente no deberia ser algo mas alla de consumir la API a traves de `file_get_contents` y `json_decode`, lo mas sencillo posible.

Basicamente eso es todo.

Comment: ¿En qué gancho de tu plugin (acción o filtro) estás usando ese código? ¿Podrías compartirlo completo y no solo el código que te falla? A parte de eso, decirte que `str_replace(" ", "%20", $url)` es una chapuza. Debes usar en su lugar [`rawurlencode()`](https://php.net/urlencode).

Comment: Como estas creando la API?, wordpress tiene su propio sistema rest api que puedes usar, te recomiendo leer https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/ tambien, para acceder a objetos como "get_the_title()" debes o pasar un POST ID o estar en un loop, de lo contrario tomara el query del page/post actual.

Comment: @OscarGarcia rgacias por su respuesta. Apenas estoy comenzando a crear el plugin, el codigo que muestro en la publicacion es el comienzo, el problema es que llegue hasta esa parte porque no pude obtener el title de la pagina actual, y esa es mi duda ¿cómo usar / llamar / traer / obtener el titulo de cualquier pagina actual en el codigo del plugin? Simplemente ahi es donde esta mi duda, con eso seria mas que suficiente para poder continuar.

Comment: @JefferzonBol gracias por su respuesta. La API ya esta creada, en realidad es bastante simple. Para acceder a sus registros lo estoy haciendo a traves de file_get_contents() y json_decode(). Tambien vi que wordpress tiene su propio sistema de API que puedo usar, pero por ahora es algo complejo para mi. En este caso solo estoy tratando de hacer algo muy simple que extraiga los valores que me interesan de la API y luego procedere a desconectarla / desactivarla. Por eso estoy tratando de irme por el camino mas facil, ya que la usare una vez y luego la desconectare.

Comment: He probado tu código en una de mis instalaciones de Wordpress y me he dado cuenta del error que estabas cometiendo cuando en el HTML estaba viendo el título de la página pero no en el lugar donde yo deseaba colocarlo. Al revisar la documentación me di cuenta que se necesita un parámetro para obtener el título como resultado de la llamada.

Comment: PD: No entiendo nada de lo que pones en el apartado *postdata*. ¿Está relacionado con la duda original o es otra duda nueva o adicional? Por favor, no mezclemos temas o dudas diferentes en la misma pregunta.

Comment: @OscarGarciael apartado esta relacionado con la duda original, no es una duda nueva. Gracias por tu ayuda, voy a revisar el codigo de tu respuesta y comento en breve

Answer (score 1):

En ese caso estas obteniendo un `name` de la API y lamentablemente no es a lo que me refiero. Ire por partes, comenzando por la API:

```
"https://localhost/xcr/armaduras.php?name=Plate Armor"
```

En este caso particular estoy mostrando la informacion de una armadura llamada ´`Plate Armor`´ que esta en un archivo llamado ´`armaduras`´. Eso es parte de mi API y contiene otros 4299 registros de items.

Como podras notar, esta API tiene la opcion de buscar registros a traves del `nombre del registro`, en este caso se trata de una de varias armaduras de un juego online. A travez del nombre puedo acceder a la informacion, en este caso la informacion es sobre la armadura ´`Plate Armor`´ y al entrar en ella se pueden obtener 47 registros adicionales con informacion relevante son la armadura ´`Plate Armor´`.

No hay mayor misterio acá. Es una API que muestra un monton de registros (4300) al mismo tiempo y tambien es posible obtener los registros de manera individual a traves de `?name=Nombre del Registro` al final del enlace de la API.

```
"https://localhost/xcr/armaduras.php" - Todos los registros.
"https://localhost/xcr/armaduras.php?name=Plate Armor" - Registro individual.
```

Ahora bien, para conectar a la API hago lo siguiente dentro de mi `plantilla` (ojo a esta parte):

```
        <?php 

        $titulo = get_the_title();
        $url = "https://tiblioteca.com/xcr/cascos.php?name=" . $titulo;
        $url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $url);
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
        $data = json_decode($data, true);

        echo $data['name'];
        echo '<br>';
        echo $data['spoiler'];
        echo '<br>';
        echo $data['greentext'];
        
        ?>
```

El codigo proporcionado se ejecuta en la propia plantilla, pero porque? Por que dentro de la `plantilla` puedo obtener el titulo de la pagina actual a traves de `get_the_title()`, en este caso la pagina se llama `Plate Armor`, y puedo usar ese `title` para buscar el registro con ese nombre dentro de la API concatenandolo al final del enlace:

```
$item_name = get_the_title(); // 'Plate Armor'
$url = "https://localhost/xcr/armaduras.php?name=" . $item_name;"
```

Pudiendo de ese modo, acceder al registro 'Plate Armor' al momento de entrar en la pagina llamada 'Plate Armor'.

Tengo 4300 publicaciones con nombres de items, ya que mi sitio se enfoca en recopilar y mostrar la informacion de cada objeto del juego en paginas individuales con toda su informacion relevante. Como es de esperarse, cada publicacion lleva como titulo el nombre del item.

Y mi API contiene la informacion de todos esos items y es posible acceder a cada uno de ellos si hago todo lo mencionado arriba. Por eso en mi caso obtener el titulo de la pagina es de gran importancia, ya con solo el titulo puedo mostrar cualquier dato de mi API con respecto al item de esa publicacion en particular.

Ahora bien, lo anterior funciona y lo hace de manera correcta, es el resultado esperado. Sin embargo (ateno aca), lo que quiero hacer ahora es consumir la API no desde la plantilla como he mencionado arriba, sino desde un plugin personalizado para tal fin, con la intencion de no llenar la `plantilla` con el codigo de la API.

Simplemente en vez de consumir la API desde la plantilla, me gustaria hacerlo desde un plugin.

Y cual es el problema?

El problema es que si bien todo mi codigo funciona correctamente cuando lo ejecuto en la `plantilla`, no ocurre lo mismo cuando lo hago desde el `plugin` que estoy creando para tal fin, ya que al parecer la funcion `get_the_title()` no funciona en el ambito de los plugins o eso es lo que me da a entender toda esta situacion.

En pocas palabras, llamar a `get_the_field()` desde el plugin es inutil, y para mi es vital que sea posible obtener el titulo de las paginas de alguna manera, para que cuando alguna pagina este abierta automaticamente mediante el nombre obtiene la API y sus datos.

Otra manera de entrarle al mismo problema seria preguntando:

> Es posible enviar informacion desde una `plantilla` hacia un `plugin`
> para procesar dicha informacion y devolverla a la `plantilla` ya
> procesada? Esa informacion es el titulo de la pagina.

Espero haberme explicado un poco mejor, lamento lo extenso y aprecio mucho tu voluntad de tratar de ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que, por defecto, la llamada a la función [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) envía la salida directamente a la página:

> the_title( string $before = '', string $after = '', bool $echo = true ): void|string

Para poder hacer uso de ella debes proporcionar como tercer parámetro (`$echo`) un `false`:

```
<?php
$url = "https://.../.../mi_api.php?";
/* Obtenemos el título como resultado de la llamada a the_title() */
$url .= http_build_query([
    'name' => the_title('', '', false),
]);
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

Por último, no puedes hacer uso de [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) sin parámetros para obtener el título de la página actual. Necesitas proporcionar como parámetro el artículo o identificador del que deseas conocer su título:

> get_the_title( int|WP_Post $post ): string